# Получение реальных размеров экрана Android

Tags: android, display

**Добрый день!**

Что я подразумеваю под "реальными размерами"? Ширину и высоту, не зависящие от положения устройства в пространстве. Т.е ширина самого устройства относительно его стандартного положения. Ширина устройства - величина, характеризующая количество пикселей в линии, параллельной, к примеру, логотипу бренда. Высота - противоположность. Так вот, с помощью системного сервиса **WindowManager** не удастся получить именно **реальные** размеры устройства, так как сами данные сервиса зависят от текущего положения:

```
Display display = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int height = display.getHeight();  // не то, что нужно
int width = display.getWidth();    // не то, что нужно
```

Собственно, есть ли вообще способ в Android получить **реальные** размеры дисплея?

Comment: особенно, когда это googleTV, там задача немного усложняется:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, в API уровня 8 появился замечательный метод класс Display [getRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation()) , возвращающий угол поворота экрана, относительно его нормального(стандартного) положения.

**P.S** Быть может, этого тоже кто-то не знал.